# How to calculate the intersection of two cuboids

Tags: ruby, math, geometry

I want to write a method for my Cuboid class which returns the cuboid defined by the intersection of two cuboids.

A cuboid is internally represented by an origin point and a terminus point such that the vector from the origin to the terminus is necessarily positive in all dimensions.

As a starting point (maybe helpful maybe not) the following method (in ruby) determines whether or not the two cuboids intersect.

```
def intersects? other_cuboid
  return not( self.top < other_cuboid.bottom ||
              self.bottom > other_cuboid.top ||
              self.left > other_cuboid.right ||
              self.right < other_cuboid.left ||
              self.front < other_cuboid.back ||
              self.back > other_cuboid.front )    
end
```

Intuitively it seems that there should be a fairly parsimonious solution to this problem but i can't think of it... any ideas?

Note: the cuboids are necessarily aligned to the axes

Comment: Voted to close. Without knowing what parameters the Cuboid constructor method takes, how are you supposed to return a new instance of Cuboid?

Comment: Will the "cuboids" always be axially aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay that your definition of cuboids depends on your initial choice of basis?

If all cuboids begin at the origin and then move into the positive direction of each axis, then is the intersection not just the minimum of all the co-ordinates in each direction?  i.e. intersection = min(left1, left2), min(right1, right2), etc.  Not sure I understand exactly what your cuboids are, or what you want them to be.

Alternatively if your cuboids are aligned in each direction (as it looks like they are from your definition), then you can take the new cuboid to have:

```
bottom = max(bottom1, bottom2)
top = min(top1, top2)
left = right_most(left1, left2)
```

etc...